# I Cant Return List Type from Wcf

Tags: wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, wcf-data-services

```
[DataContract]
public class UserDetails
{
    string _userid;
    string tckimlik;
    string ad;
    string tarih;
    string aciklama;
    [DataMember]
    public string userid
    {
        get { return _userid; }
        set { _userid = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Tckimlik
    {
        get { return tckimlik; }
        set { tckimlik = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Ad
    {
        get { return ad; }
        set { ad = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Tarih
    {
        get { return tarih; }
        set { tarih = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Aciklama
    {
        get { return aciklama; }
        set { aciklama = value; }
    }
}

public interface IService1
{        

    [OperationContract]
    List<UserDetails> GetAllPersons();
}
```

My Class DataContract and OperationContract given above.
My Method GetAllPersons type of List beloew.

```
 public List<UserDetails> GetAllPersons()
    {
        List<UserDetails> userL = new List<UserDetails>();
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("");
            con.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM RegistrationTable",con);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter sda = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                UserDetails us = new UserDetails()
                {
                    userid = reader[0].ToString(),
                    Tckimlik = reader[1].ToString(),
                    Ad = reader[2].ToString(),
                    Tarih = reader[3].ToString(),
                    Aciklama = reader[4].ToString()
                };
                userL.Add(us);
            }
            con.Close();
            return userL;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

The Code above is in WCF Service. I want to call GetAllPersons method in Xamarin. But i have trouble with it. My Xamarin code is below.

```
 void getVisitor()
    {
        List<ServiceReference1.UserDetails> getir = new List<ServiceReference1.UserDetails>();
        getir = service.GetAllPersonsAsync();
        
    }
```

When i wanted to call method in service, i get an error given below.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference1.GetAllPersonsResponse>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ServiceReference1.UserDetails>'   XamarinCRUD C:\Users\Eyyub\source\repos\XamarinCRUD\XamarinCRUD\XamarinCRUD\MainPage.xaml.cs    59  Active

Who can hint me, appreciate it!
Best for all!
**I also checked logs and no show. Some says that WCF doesnt (de)serialize List return type. Is it true? if yes, what is the solution?. When i used same service through FormApp, works fine. But Xamarin doesnt..**

Comment: Don't use WCF.  Seriously, it is old and there are many better options available.  2nd, use `await` when calling `async` methods

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for replying. I need to use WCF in this step, i used like      ;               
    getir = await service.GetAllPersonsAsync(); and async void getVisitor(){    but problem stills

Comment: var persons =  await service.GetAllPersonsAsync();
getir = persons?.ToList();
Try this way

Comment: @Ranjit ; GetAllPersonsResponse does not contain a definition for ToList and no accesible extension method ToList accepting a a first argument XamarinCRUD type GetAllPersonsResponse could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)..... Got an error given. ToList() is not be able to use.

Comment: The Xamarin platform support for WCF is limited to text-encoded SOAP messages over HTTP/HTTPS using the BasicHttpBinding class. Here is the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/wcf

Comment: @TheobaldDu Thanks for replying me! I will check it.

Comment: I don't see where you are implementing your IService1 interface in your Service Implementation code.  Also, shouldn't there be a DataMember in your DataContract that desccibes the List of multiple users you want serialized and  returned?

Comment: Something like:  [DataContract]
    public class MultipleUsers
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<UserDetails> UsersDetailList { get; set; } = new List<UserDetails>();
    }